# At what point does adding more threads stop helping?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a computer with 4 cores, and I have a program that creates an N x M grid, which could range from a 1 by 1 square up to a massive grid. The program then fills it with numbers and performs calculations on each number, averaging them all together until they reach roughly the same number. The purpose of this is to create a LOT of busy work, so that computing with parallel threads is a necessity.

If we have a optional parameter to select the number of threads used, what number of threads would best optimize the busy work to make it run as quickly as possible?

Would using 4 threads be 4 times as fast as using 1 thread? What about 15 threads? 50? At some point I feel like we will be limited by the hardware (number of cores) in our computer and adding more threads will stop helping (and might even hinder?)

Comment: Typically, even on a multi-core system, performance does not scale linearly with the number of threads. Especially if you need to do some kind of synchronization between the threads. And if the systems total number of threads is larger than the number of cores (which it usually is unless you're on a dedicated system of some kind) then all threads have to "fight" for the cores you have. And sooner or later you will reach a tipping point where the system spends more time switching between threads than it does actually running them.

Comment: As most of the time the answer is "It depends." In general you don't get more power if you add more threads unless you can also use another core or your threads are blocked by I/O. This means more than 4 threads will probably not give any performance benefits for pure number crunching. Furthermore your problems asks for tight synchronization of the threads. You can execute one run of averaging and then you need to handle the borders of the areas modified by each thread. This also limits performance gain

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the system can only change the set of running threads when it is entered by means of a system call or hardware interrupt/driver.  With the OP's CPU-intensive example there seem to be no syscalls, and no I/O completions, leaving only page-faults and the periodic timer interrupts as points where a reschedule could be run.  The timer interval is usually fixed and unrelated to the number of ready threads: it doesn't matter if there are 4 or 4000 rea\dy threads, a reschedule would still only happen every 10ms or whatever. So, what 'tipping point'?  Page faults?

Comment: ''If we have a optional parameter to select the number of threads used' well, then you could simply test it, no?  Test results are much more satisfying than guesstimating beforehand:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to answer is to give a first overview on how threads are managed by the system. Nowadays all processors are actually multi-core and multi-thread per core, but for sake of simplicity let's first imagine a single core processor with single thread. This is physically limited in performing only a single task at the time, but we are still capable of running multitask programs.

So how is this possible? Well it is simply illusion!

The CPU is still performing a single task at the time, but switches between one and the other giving the illusion of multitasking. This process of changing from one task to the other is named [Context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).

During a Context switch all the data related to the task that is running is saved and the data related to the next task is loaded. Depending on the architecture of the CPU data can be saved in registers, cache, RAM, etc. The more the technology advances, the more performing solutions have been discovered. When the task is resumed, the whole data is fetched and the task continues its operations.

This concept introduces many issues in managing tasks, like:

1. [Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)
2. Synchronization
3. [Starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))
4. [Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

There are other points, but this is just a quick list since the question does not focus on this.

Getting back to your question:

> If we have a optional parameter to select the number of threads used, what number of threads would best optimize the busy work to make it run as quickly as possible?
>
> Would using 4 threads be 4 times as fast as using 1 thread? What about 15 threads? 50? At some point I feel like we will be limited by the hardware (number of cores) in our computer and adding more threads will stop helping (and might even hinder?)

Short answer: It depends!

As previously said, to switch between a task and another, a Context switch is required. To perform this some storing and fetching data operations are required, but these operations are just an overhead for you computation and don't give you directly any advantage. So having too many tasks requires a high amount of Context switching, thus meaning a lot of computational time wasted! So at the end your task might be running slower than with less tasks.

Also, since you tagged this question with pthreads, it is also necessary to check that the code is compiled to run on multiple HW cores. Having a multi core CPU does not guarantee that you multitask code will run on multiple HW cores!

In your particular case of application:

> I have a computer with 4 cores, and I have a program that creates an N x M grid, which could range from a 1 by 1 square up to a massive grid. The program then fills it with numbers and performs calculations on each number, averaging them all together until they reach roughly the same number. The purpose of this is to create a LOT of busy work, so that computing with parallel threads is a necessity.

Is a good example of concurrent and data independent computing. This sort of tasks run great on GPU, since operations don't have data correlation and concurrent computing is performed in hardware (modern GPU have thousands of computing cores!)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for the answer!